# How do I grab the files for an array of paths in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, filepath

I have some functionality that pulls profile image file names for each user in my app. Let’s say I need the profile images for 10 users. My app would make 10 requests to the server.

However, I realised this was really inefficient, so I decided to write a function that takes an array of paths and returns the file name for the image in each of those paths.

I store each user’s profile image in a directory that matches their user ID, for example `/some/path/userid/profile-image.jpg`

**This is how the simplified function looks:**

```
 getProfilePhotoFileNamesForUsers: async (server, request) => {
    
    var imageFilesArray = [];

    try {

        for await (const userId of userIdsArray) {

            const path = `${process.cwd()}/uploads/${userId}`;
    
            Fse.exists(path, async (exists) => {
                    
    
                        if (exists) {
                                                   
                            const fileName = await Fse.readdir(`${process.cwd()}/uploads/${userId}`);
    
                            let fileNameObject = {
                                user_id: userId,
                                file_name: fileName[0]
                            };
        
                            imageFilesArray.push(fileNameObject);
    
                        } else {

                            let fileNameObject = {
                                userId: userId,
                                fileName: undefined
                            };
    
                            imageFilesArray.push(fileNameObject);
                        }
    
                });
    
            };
                     
               return imageFilesArray
        }

    catch(error) {

      console.log(error)

    }
}
```

Initially, I used `forEach` but discovered a sync/await wouldn’t work with this kind of for loop. The imageFilesArray was always returned before the forEach loop completed.

I ended up using the `for-of` loop you see above. However the result is still the same. The array gets updated, but it’s variable is always returned before the for-of loop starts.

I also tried using promises, but the result is the same. This is why I’m wondering if I’m doing things the wrong way.

Is there a way I can just provide an array of paths (constructed by providing an array of user ids), and get back an array of matching directories I can further manipulate? This would mean I wouldn’t need to use a for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to re-adapt it to your code since I can't really test it without the `userIds`directory, but you can use the `map()` function instead of your for loop.
Here is an async version that should work for your example:

```js
let userIdsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const getProfilePhotoFileNamesForUsers = async () => {
  // Use the map() function instead of a for loop
  return Promise.all(userIdsArray.map(async (userId) => {
    // Get teh corresponding path
    const path = `${process.cwd()}/uploads/${userId}`;
    // Await to see if the path exists
    let exists = await Fse.exists(path)
    return {
      user_id: userId,
      file_name: exists ?
        await Fse.readdir(`${process.cwd()}/uploads/${userId}`)[0] : undefined
    }
  }))
}

getProfilePhotoFileNamesForUsers().then(data => console.log(data))
```

I hope it makes sense!